# Entity Framework - How to navigate in List<T> elements

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4

I have two models Garden and Flower

```
public class Garden
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } // Default value: Garden #[Id]

    // Location.
    public int LocationX { get; set; }
    public int LocationY { get; set; }

    // Flowers.
    public virtual List<Flower> Flowers { get; set; }
}

public class Flower
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }

    public DateTime LastWatered { get; set; }
    public DateTime Planted { get; set; }
}

public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Garden> Gardens { get; set; }
}
```

And now, I need to select a flower by Id. I got to this, but I'm not sure that's the good way. How should I do it? Do you have any articles about that?

```
var garden = _db.Gardens.Where(g => g.Id == gardenId).SingleOrDefault();
var flower = garden.Flowers.Where(f => f.Id == flowerId).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: If this is not the right way, i've been doing it wrong for over 2 years. I wouldn't worry, this code is ok :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest this:

```
 var garden = _db.Gardens.SingleOrDefault(g => g.Id == gardenId);

 Flower flower = null;

 if (garden != null)
 {
     flower = garden.Flowers.SingleOrDefault(f => f.Id == flowerId);
 }
```

Instead of using Where first and SingleOrDefault afterwards just use SingleOrDefault.

**EDIT**

As @JoachimIsaksson suggested, I have added a null reference check for garden to avoid the possible NullReferenceException.

Comment: ...except that if there is no such garden, the code will throw a nullref exception.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson if there is no such garden, SingleOrDefault() will return *null*. That by itself wont cause a nullref exc, if you try to do something with the *garden*, then it will.

Comment: @Thousand Yes, like the second line does.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson sorry, i missed that ;)

Comment: Thank you, now I feel much better about it ;).

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite it using another syntax and do the whole select in one database access. This will also eliminate any need for null checks;

```
// this will find the flower with the correct id 
// only if it's also in the garden with the correct id

var result = (from garden in _db.Gardens
              from flower in garden.Flowers
              where garden.Id == gardenId 
                 && flower.Id == flowerId
              select flower).SingleOrDefault();
```